# Como tirar barra de um modal

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Olá, como tiro essa barra cinza de cima do modal ??

[image]

```
$(function() 
    {
        var dialog, form,
        dialog = $( "#painel_fazer_upload" ).dialog
        ({
          autoOpen: false,
          height: 520,
          width: 500,
          modal: true,
        });

        $( "#painel_upload" ).button().on( "click", function()
        {
          dialog.dialog( "open" );
        });
    });
```

Comment: Olá @lucas-carezia! Qual o plugin para gerar o modal você esta usando?

Comment: code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js e code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível fazer a remoção do fundo e da borda cinza do titulo do modal sobrescrevendo o CSS original do jQuery UI da seguinte maneira:

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar{
    //tira a cor de fundo cinza
    background: transparent;
    //tira a cor da borda
    border: none;
}
```

Não se esqueça de adicionar estas linhas logo após a inclusão do arquivo de CSS do jQuery UI para que estas regras da classe sejam reescritas.

Outra opção é altera-las direto no arquivo CSS se for possível.

Answer (score 1):

Deves fazer isso com CSS. A classe que tem essa `div` é `.ui-dialog-titlebar` e se usares CSS fica automáticamente invisivel para todos os dialog. Podes fazer assim:

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar{
  visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/gb7w37de/1/

Se o que queres é mudar a côr podes mudar parametros no CSS como `background-color`, `border`, ou específicamente `border-color`.

Podes também fazer isso com JavaScript/jQuery. Nesse caso algo como `$('.ui-dialog-titlebar').css('visibility', 'hidden');` ou aplicar uma classe de CSS.

#### Exemplo via JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/gb7w37de/

Comment: Funcionou bem, eu tenho outra duvida diferente da pergunta, caso eu queira fechar manualmente a janela, qual código devo usar ??

Comment: @LucasCarezia nesse caso podes usar `$( "#painel_fazer_upload" ).dialog('close');`